# Cannot access 'http://dean.technology' but can access server using any sub-domain

Tags: dns, webserver, azure

I've got the domain dean.technology connected to an azure web server but accessing `http://dean.technology/` returns an error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

On the DNS server I have successfully pointed sub-domain to different servers and event attached `www, cookies, and *` as possible sub-domain. Since I've pointed the `*` sub-domain I can access my website using any sub-domain. I want and it will load the page ie:

```
wget http://stack.dean.technology/ => 200 OK
wget http://overflow.dean.technology/ => 200 OK
wget http://isGreat.dean.technology/ => 200 OK
```

but still cannot access the dean.technology. What do you think is going wrong?

Comment: +1 for not being paranoid and actually providing useful information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly set up the subdomains in DNS, but not the "root" A record.

When I do a "dig dean.technology A" it does not return a result, however doing a "dig stack.dean.technology A" does.

You need to add the appropriate records for "dean.technology".  I've not used azueredns, but you probably need to repeat the steps you took for *.dean.technology, and repeat them, but leave out the "*" character.

Comment: I've created an A-Record on my DNS provider `40.113.81.82` which is what azure asks for (and to create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to deanmeehanblog.azurewebsites.net) and is how I got any domains working. Azure then lets you add these "verified" addresses to the list of domain names for the server.

Comment: The thing is you have not created a valid A record for "dean.technology" (and you can't use a CNAME)  Try adding a subdomain called "@" with an A record pointng to 40.113.81.82 and see if that works - Based on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/#add-an-a-record-for-your-custom-domain I think it will.

Comment: Thanks alot, finally got around to changing it. Do you know what does the @ symbol actually do in DNS in my case?

Comment: The @ symbol specifies “the root of the zone (domain)“ ie as opposed to a subdomain.